# add foxit reader as my default pdf reader in html canvas

Tags: php, html, pdf

I need to set foxit reader as a pdf reder in my HTML canvas . I hope the HTML canvas is picking the default pdf reader of the browser . I have enabled the Foxit 
pdf plugin and disabled the Acrobate reder in firefox  but when i restart the firefox it showes the default reader . Is it possible to change the default pdf redaer of the browser does it applicable on all the browsers . Please Help.

Comment: What browsers do you need this to work in? I ask because Chrome and Edge have their own PDF viewer built in which will handle the PDF regardless of the default viewer.

Comment: Hi I need to do this in firefox .